# Simple way to insert a string into another string - PHP

Tags: php

How can I add string to another string after a specific character in PHP? Strings are coming from Database.

```
$stringDB= "FZE-17-01";
$string_add="RTL";
```

Final output= FZE-**RTL**-17-01

I tried functions but I don't want to use a position based function like **substr_replace** after 4 characters, etc. Any good alternative. $string_add after first **-**

Comment: what is the reason for not wanting to use substr_replace?

Comment: Just use `strpos` to find the first occurrence then use your existing code

Comment: @xs0 because first 3 characters might increase to 4 or 5

Comment: @Zack: Then you'd need to find the position of whatever character you want to target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of many variants is to use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$arr = explode('-', $stringDB);
array_splice($arr, 1,0,  $string_add);

echo implode('-', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you.

```
$stringDB= "FZE-17-01";
$string_add="RTL";

echo $newstr = substr_replace($stringDB, $string_add, 4, 0);
```

[PHP substr_replace](http://php.net/substr_replace)

Comment: Your solution is missing the hyphen after the inserted string: FZE-RTL-17-01. Your solution: FZE-RTL17-01.
Also since the question is: How can i insert a string to another string **after a specific character** i would suggest you replace `4` with `strpos($stringDB, '-')`